# Android usb storage refresh

Tags: android, usb, storage, refresh, android-mediascanner

There is a program currently being developed.

The app works with the usb connected When the file in usb is changed,

the file is loaded as the changed file at the first time.

However, if you try again with a connection in the future, the loaded file will continue to load the previous file, not the latest file.

I searched for various methods and tried to refresh using a scanner among them.

It was not a solution.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Codes I Tried

```
1. MediaScannerConnection.scanFile (mContext, new String[] {getStorageDirectories()}, null, null);


2. final Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
   final Uri contentUri = ff.getUri();
   scanIntent.setData(contentUri);
   mContext.sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
```

Comment: I see no file. And i dont see you loading a file. And what would scanning bring?

Comment: 1. I have a device connected using a usb otg.
2. A file change occurs on the connected device.
3. However, there is information about the file that has not changed on the android phone.
4. For this, I used the scanner function, but it changes only once the first time and does not change afterwards.
5. Is there a way to refresh when USB is connected?

Comment: Sorry, this is all too vague for me and dont know about which information you are talking.

Comment: I solved it.
Thank you for your answer